# Flask taking too much processor

Tags: python, flask

How can I measure , which parts of my Flask project are taking too much   of processor time? And how to reduce it?  I'll add code if needed, but its a little big code. So far it takes like 50-100% of processor. (i used command `top`)

ok i used `from werkzeug.contrib.profiler import ProfilerMiddleware` to profile

here is result of profiler, the most slowest function, when i opened index page in browser. Is it any help?

```
PATH: '/auth/login'
         47946 function calls (44288 primitive calls) in 0.232 seconds
```

Ordered by: internal time, call count
   List reduced from 618 to 25 due to restriction <25>

ncalls  tottime  percall  cumtime  percall filename:lineno(function)
        1    0.033    0.033    0.043    0.043 /home-fri/hojny/.virtualenvs/e-vzd                                                                               elavanie/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/ext.py:12()
   638/29    0.018    0.000    0.040    0.001 /home-fri/hojny/.virtualenvs/e-vzd                                                                                    elavanie/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/nodes.py:184(find_all)
      364    0.017    0.000    0.018    0.000 /home-fri/hojny/.virtualenvs/e-vzd                                                                                     elavanie/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/lexer.py:230(**new**)
       18    0.017    0.001    0.020    0.001 /home-fri/hojny/.virtualenvs/e-vzd                                                                                        elavanie/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/compiler.py:1212(visit_Output)
       75    0.016    0.000    0.017    0.000 /home-fri/hojny/.virtualenvs/e-vzd                                                                                        elavanie/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/lexer.py:538(_normalize_newlin                                                                                        es)
     4705    0.014    0.000    0.016    0.000 /home-fri/hojny/.virtualenvs/e-vzd                                                                                        elavanie/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/nodes.py:148(iter_fields)
     2734    0.013    0.000    0.032    0.000 /home-fri/hojny/.virtualenvs/e-vzd                                                                                        elavanie/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/nodes.py:164(iter_child_nodes)
      467    0.012    0.000    0.019    0.000 /home-fri/hojny/.virtualenvs/e-vzd                                                                                        elavanie/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/lexer.py:593(tokeniter)
    210/2    0.010    0.000    0.015    0.007 /home-fri/hojny/.virtualenvs/e-vzd                                                                                        elavanie/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/visitor.py:58(generic_visit)
        1    0.010    0.010    0.010    0.010 /home-fri/hojny/.virtualenvs/e-vzd                                                                                        elavanie/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/ext.py:41(Extension)
     8925    0.007    0.000    0.007    0.000 {isinstance}
     1713    0.005    0.000    0.005    0.000 {method 'match' of '_sre.SRE_Patte                                                                                        rn' objects}
     4315    0.004    0.000    0.004    0.000 {getattr}
    998/4    0.003    0.000    0.093    0.023 /home-fri/hojny/.virtualenvs/e-vzd                                                                                        elavanie/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/visitor.py:34(visit)
   540/68    0.002    0.000    0.013    0.000 /home-fri/hojny/.virtualenvs/e-vzd                                                                                        elavanie/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/visitor.py:41(generic_visit)
      206    0.002    0.000    0.003    0.000 /home-fri/hojny/.virtualenvs/e-vzd                                                                                        elavanie/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/nodes.py:127(**init**)
      362    0.002    0.000    0.056    0.000 /home-fri/hojny/.virtualenvs/e-vzd                                                                                        elavanie/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/lexer.py:548(wrap)
      998    0.002    0.000    0.003    0.000 /home-fri/hojny/.virtualenvs/e-vzd                                                                                        elavanie/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/visitor.py:26(get_visitor)
        2    0.002    0.001    0.002    0.001 {compile}
      575    0.001    0.000    0.002    0.000 /home-fri/hojny/.virtualenvs/e-vzd                                                                                        elavanie/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/lexer.py:240(test)
  748/386    0.001    0.000    0.058    0.000 {next}
     78/9    0.001    0.000    0.002    0.000 /home-fri/hojny/.virtualenvs/e-vzd                                                                                        elavanie/lib/python2.7/sre_compile.py:32(_compile)
    45/10    0.001    0.000    0.004    0.000 /home-fri/hojny/.virtualenvs/e-vzd                                                                                        elavanie/lib/python2.7/sre_parse.py:388(_parse)
      364    0.001    0.000    0.002    0.000 /home-fri/hojny/.virtualenvs/e-vzd                                                                                        elavanie/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/jinja2/compiler.py:492(write)
       42    0.001    0.000    0.001    0.000 /home-fri/hojny/.virtualenvs/e-vzd                                                                                        elavanie/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/werkzeug/urls.py:441(url_quote)

Comment: Use the [python profiler](https://docs.python.org/3/library/profile.html)

Comment: please explain more about what you have already done

Comment: btw its taking this 50%+ when im just running server and not doing anything... is it standard for flask? im not sending requests... nothing... it just waits for requests in its loop and still takes 50%+ processor
btw im using flask-script to run runserver

Comment: guys, i edited the question using some info from profiler

Comment: hmm this would show it for 1 request, but it wouldnt show what is running outside the request context-

Comment: so how to proceed? profiler sents statistic only after i invoke request..

Comment: i want mainly to reduce CPU % use , and this profiler just shows how much of time it takes , nothing about CPU.. or does it?

Comment: david, Werkzeug==0.10.1

Comment: pls help :u , i just tried another project with old werkzeug, and then with newest werkzeug, and both were CPU< 5% ....

so i guess its not in the werkzeug version.. it must be something with my code..but i dont know how to find out where is fault

Comment: so i uploaded application folder + other important files here http://www.filedropper.com/flask  ,  starting app by ./manage.py runserver ,  it uses Flask-Script extension

Comment: please help me , im lost